# What is the right way to handle mode parameters in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My app has a number of ambient properties, like the current CountryId, DocumentMode, etc.  As I learned [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298967/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-permalinks-when-the-page-depends-on-the-session), the current value of these properties should not be stored in the Session, but rather sent in the query string on every page request.  So far so good.

So when I build a page, I want to arrange that all the action links look like this:

/controller/action?CountryId=x&DocumentMode=y&...

I can easily do this by checking the query string and slipping in the current value of each of these variables.

The question is, what's the right way to notify the app when one of the values changes?

Specifically, at the top of each view, I have a select dropdown that shows, e.g., all the countries.  What should happen when you select a new one?

Right now, the change triggers a javascript function call that replaces the CountryId in the query string, and calls an action that just reloads the original page, but with the new CountryId set, and so the new action links are rebuilt.  But this seems sort of kludgy.  Is there a more elegant way to just update all the links on the page without needing a server refresh to do this?  (I could always cook up some script to do this, but it doesn't seem trivial, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's a built in way to do this.)

Any help much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to keep things simple for the time being and just refresh the whole page, which recreates all of the links.  My app is low volume and this suffices for now.  If I ever need to build an app where the server can't be foolishly stressed like that, I'll see about the swap-in-place solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the part of the page that changes in a partial view and reload that view via AJAX each time a control is changed.

[Partial rendering after page loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498914/partial-rendering-after-page-loaded)

Alternatively you could just write some javascript to update all the links. Post some code and I'm sure you'll get some suggestions on a good way to write it.

Comment: I suppose that re-rendering only the parts containing links that need to be recreated would be better than refreshing the whole page, but I'm not sure the increased complexity is worth it, since in this case *almost all* the links would need to change, and I still have the server call.  But the link modifying idea may be reasonable.  Probably it would be easy and fast enough to loop through all the links and swap out the parameter value.  I will update my question with that in mind.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, the current value of the parameter is in the query string of the current page, and changing all the links but not updating the value in the address bar seems...untidy at best.  Is there a way to update the address bar without actually navigating away?

Comment: In older browsers you can only change what is after the hash. HTML5 browsers will allow you to change it. https://github.com/balupton/history.js